# How to connect two database through JDBC? Is it possible?

Tags: java, jdbc

I have tried to connect the mysql database with the frontend with the help of JDBC driver. But i dont know how acna we implement connectivity to connect the two different databases with  each other with the help of JDBC driver.

Comment: What do you want to do? Migrate data between two databases? If both DBs are from the same vendor, you'll get some out of box tools to migrate data. For DBs from different vendors, there are third party tools available.

Comment: You really need to clarify what you want to achieve. But to be clear: connecting two database to each other through JDBC in itself is not possible, but a single program can of course connect to two database and query data from one database and insert it into another.

Comment: A single program as in? Could you please elaborate more? I am bit new to the topic.

Answer (score 1):

You can create two connections. One for the first database and the other for the second database. You can send commands to the first database using the first connection and you can send commands to the second database using the second connection. Your application will serve the purpose of connecting the two databases as you can select rows from one database, parse them and insert the resulting records into the other.

Comment: I can create two connections. But connection as in? I am bit confused as i am new to this field.

Comment: @dhruvsheth7 Start with a [basic JDBC tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html), and rephrase your question to be more specific. As it stands we have no idea what you are actually asking

Comment: @MarkRotteveel i know the basic JDBC connectivity. I dont know how to connect the two database with each other. I want to transfer the data from db to another. Thanks though.I am stuck at how to connect them with each other

Comment: @dhruvsheth7 There is no magic, and no standard way to 'connect' two database to each other using JDBC. You need to implement this yourself: Select using a statement from `connectionToDb1`, insert using a statement from `connectionToDb2`

Comment: The application connecting to two separate databases using two connections is the connection between the two databases. You must program the behavior of your connection between databases. There is no easy way, you have to do it yourself according to your desire and/or specification.

Answer (score 1):

There is no magic in JDBC that allows you to '*connect the two database with each other*'. You need to code this yourself. You create two connections, one for each database and then you write the queries and transformations to get your data from database 1 to database 2.

```
try (
    Connection connectionToDb1 = DriverManager.getConnection(
        "jdbc:firebirdsql://serverA/database1", "username", "password");
    Connection connectionToDb2 = DriverManager.getConnection(
        "jdbc:firebirdsql://serverB/database2", "username", "password");
    Statement selectFrom1 = connectionToDb1.createStatement();
    ResultSet rsFrom1 = selectFrom1.executeQuery(
        "SELECT columnA, columnB FROM tableX");
    PreparedStatement insertTo2 = connectionToDb2.prepareStatement(
        "INSERT INTO tableY(column1, column2) VALUES (?, ?)");
) {
   while (rsFrom1.next()) {
       insertTo2.setString(1, rsFrom1.getString("columnA"));
       insertTo2.setString(2, rsFrom1.getString("columnB"));
       insertTo2.executeUpdate();
   }
}
```

Note that this isn't a complete example: for production purposes you would disable auto commit, and use batch updates.

There are tools that can do this for you, but tool and library suggestions are off topic on SO, but I'd suggest you search for ETL (or extract, transform, load), or maybe for datapump.